# How do I break lines for a method definition with many parameters in C#?

Tags: c#

In c#, when we are writing a method which gets for example 6 parameters, and we want to break the parameters in 3 lines, how could we break the lines?

Comment: Is your question about the syntax for breaking a line, or an approach to where in the list to break it?

Comment: First one: sysntax for breaking a line specially when we want to pass parameters to the method.

Comment: I get the impression that he's coming from the world of VB where an underscore '_' is used to break a line. Trying this in c# won't work, so he probably didn't know what to do. 

I've seen this with a few devs going from vb to c#. Funny how sometimes the simplest things trips one up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C# you do not need to specify anything in particular to break a line into several on-screen lines.

So a method which would look like this in vb:

```
sub someMethod(param1 as String, _
    param2 as Integer, _
    param3 as Boolean)

    doSomething()

end sub
```

Will look like this in C#

```
public void someMethod(string param1,
    int param2, 
    bool param3) {

    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 21):

In C# you can break the lines after any parameter name (either before of after the comma). [Stylecop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) (the Microsoft coding style guideline checker) suggests either all parameters on one line, or one per line - nothing in between. Like so:

```
public void Method(int param1, int param2, int param3, int param4, int param5, int param6)
{

}

public void Method(
    int param1,
    int param2,
    int param3,
    int param4,
    int param5,
    int param6)
{

}
```

But, there is no requirement to follow these guidelines, you can do whatever suits your internal style.

Comment: This is the standard way in the English language. I can never understand why people read english writing all day, and then when coding they came up all sorts of different formatting for organizing text. For the most part, follow the English language. Enumerations are either done all on the same line _This, that, and the other._, or all on new lines each (_like bullet points_). Function paramteres have no reason to not follow that style. It makes me wonder why people engage in re-engineering these kinds of things. Thanks, you did good.

Comment: This is perfect, I NEED tool that would do that automatically, it seems that [dotnet format](https://github.com/dotnet/format) isn't capable to do so

Answer (score 14):

I guess you can just simply add the line breaks:

```
private void SomeMethod(int param1, int param2, 
                        int param3, int param4,
                        int param5, int param6)
{
    // do something
}
```

In C# (unlike VB.NET - at least up to now; [this will change in VS2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865x40k4(VS.100).aspx), check "Implicit Line Continuation" about half way down on the page) you can introduce line breaks in the code pretty much anywhere. You don't need to specify that the code statement continues on the next line; that is taken care of by the syntax.

If you have a method declared as my sample above, this does not set up any requirements on how you call it. The following examples are all valid:

```
SomeMethod(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
SomeMethod(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    6);
SomeMethod(1
    , 2, 3, 4
    , 5, 6);
```

Comment: Can you expand your VB.NET note to say that there is stuff coming in 4.0 making _ line breaks redundant in general (rather than just alluding to it)

Answer (score 10):

You can break the lines using the ENTER key, towards the right side of your keyboard.

Comment: What if he has the RETURN key instead?
Actually I've the "Invio" button... XD

Comment: It seems like some people would put the entire function on one line if they didn't accidentally hit that thing every once in awhile...

Comment: @kentaromiura thank you, 2023 ENTER did not work for me, but RETURN did.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean in terms of the layout, there are various options, such as:

Option 1:

```
public void Foo(int first, int second,
                int third, int fourth,
                int fifth, int sixth)
```

Option 2:

```
public void Foo(int first, int second,
    int third, int fourth,
    int fifth, int sixth)
```

Option 3:

```
public void Foo(
    int first, int second,
    int third, int fourth,
    int fifth, int sixth)
```

Option 4:

```
public void Foo
    (int first, int second,
     int third, int fourth,
     int fifth, int sixth)
```

Personally I like option 1, but it has two disadvantages:

- You need to lay the parameters out again if you change the method name
- You don't get as much space per line, because it's already indented a fair distance

Failing that, I'd generally go with option 2 or 3. Option 4 looks pretty ugly to me.

Comment: @Ruben: Have deleted my comment. Feel free to add a new one :)

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean? like this?

```
public void MyMethod(int Parameter1, string Parameter2
                   , long Parameter3, float Parameter4
                   , double Parameter5, char Parameter6)
{
    //Method Functionality
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void Foo(object Parameter0, object Parameter1,
    object Parameter2, object Parameter3,
    object Parameter4, object Parameter5)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

6 parameters / 3 lines = 2 parameters per line? Although I'd say that looks a little funny because there's extra room on each line.

Note that in C#, you can just use a line break - nothing fancy needed (VB's "`_`" for instance).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood rightly what you are saying then,,,

```
public void myMethod ( type parameter1, 
                       type parameter2,
                       .
                       .
                       type parameterN) 
{
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Comment: -1 to bring it back to 0: Wanted on specifically 3 lines. Other answers are clearer and explain why, not just give the answer