# Break Long code lines in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#

In Visual Studio 2008, if I have a long line of code, how can i get that to breakup into multiple lines?

```
public static void somemethod(param1, param2, param3, more params etc...)
```

How can I make this 1 line of code span 2 or 3 lines?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Hit the enter key.

```
public static somemethod(param1, 
    param2, 
    param3, 
    more params etc...)
```

...is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe it was that simple and obvious.

Comment: Likewise, as far as compilation is concerned, there's no reason you need to put *any* newlines in your code, except for preprocessor directives which traditionally need to be newline delimited.  Of course, if you want humans to be able to understand your code, newlines are strongly recommended :)

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118811/how-do-i-break-lines-for-a-method-definition-with-many-parameters-in-c/1118825#1118825

Answer (score 13):

C# is not line based, so you can split the statements anywhere but inside an identifier:

```
public static void somemethod(
   int param1,
   int param2,
   int param3,
   more params etc...
)
```

You can even write something like:

```
for
(
int
i
=
0
;
i
<
10
;
i
++
) 
{
Console
.
WriteLine
(
i
)
;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To break strings you can place a `_` at the break in VB.Net and in C# you put `@` before the string.

Code in C#:

```
string s=@"sdsdsdsd
dfdfdfdfdf
fdfdfdfdf";
```

Code in VB

```
s="fdfdfdfdfdf _
dfdfdfdfdfdf "
```

Comment: This declares a verbatim string, and so the line break and whitespace will also end up in your string. It is not funcionally equivalent to the line continuation character in VB.

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple options:

1. Tools > Options > All Languages > General > Enable Word Wrap
2. Use the following regex in the Find In Files dialog to find long lines (120 characters in this case) in the project so you can split them?
   `^.^120`

Edit: Seeing the marked answer - I rather assumed that part was known. :o

Comment: @Arnis: Note on #2 here - I had a project lead many years ago who would revert entire SCC check-ins if someone submitted a line over 120 chars long. :fail:

Comment: Yes, but revert? Just fix the line iff it becomes a problem in an area you're actually working on. I can fit over 300 characters on a line without scrolling, forcing wrapping while I work is just a waste of my time and screen real estate.

Comment: I try to use an optimized setup for code display in my viewports, usually organized in columns since 16:9 screens allow for such little vertical space. In order to do this, I try to enforce a rule of 78/80/100/120 max line width in chars, depending on the amount of lobbying I can do. But if people still insert 300 chars long declarations in the codebase, at least I have word wrap to avoid going insane while I reformat it correctly.
Please, think of your miserable colleagues or successors when you insert  300 chars wide lines in your codebase.

Answer (score 2):

You mean how do you do it automatically, or by hand?  There are some tools like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) that have features to "wrap" long lines of code.  If you want to do it manually, then just press the Enter key anywhere that's not in the middle of an identifier.

Comment: Resharper is great, but one of the things I don't like is how it wraps lines.  I personally prefer to manually line things up the way apathetic has shown.  Some folks like it automatic, though.  +1

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't need any line continuation characters (the way basic does). Just insert a line break anywhere in the line.

```
public static somemethod(type param1, 
                         type param2,
                         type param3)
{

}
```

works just fine.

If you look at linq and fluent interface samples you will see some idiomatic ways to break long lines:

```
builder
   .AddSomething()
   .If((z) => z.SomeCondition)
   .AddSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer provides one way to divide a line into multiple lines, but I just wanted to add this; how dividing lines can increase readability. It's just a matter of choice what we want to follow.

What I don't try to follow, as I find it a little hard to differentiate parameter from the function name.

```
 // Arguments on first line forbidden when not using vertical alignment.
 var a  = someObject.LongFunctionName("csharp", "value 1", "value 2"
          OtherFunction(val1, val2))

 // Further indentation required as indentation is not distinguishable.
 public void MyFunction(
             value1, value2, 
             Value3,
             value4)
 {
     //..
 }

 // Further indentation required for parameters.
 public void MyFunction(
     value1, value2, Value3, value4)
 {
     //..
 }
```

What I generally go for

```
 // Aligned with opening delimiter.
 var a  = someObject.LongFunctionName("csharp", "value 1", "value 2"
                                      OtherFunction(val1, val2))

 // Aligned with opening delimiter.                         
 public void MyFunction(value1, value2, value3,
                        value4)
 {
     //..
 }

 // Add a tab spaces (an extra level of indentation) to distinguish arguments from the rest.                              
 public void MyFunction(
                value1, value2, value3,
                value4)
 {
     //..
 }

 var a  = someObject.LongFunctionName(
                         "csharp", "value 1", "value 2"
                         OtherFunction(val1, val2));
```

At the end, in case of any doubts use your judgement what suits the best.